# How to set OneToOneField to null?

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.7, django-queryset, django-related-manager

I have model with a OneToOneField that may be null:

```
solution_for = models.OneToOneField('QNAQuestion', related_name='solution', blank=True, null=True)
```

Sometimes it has a value that needs to be removed in a view. What is the syntax to null it? It's a very simple question, but google doesn't really help.

I already tried:

```
obj.solution_for = None
obj.solution_for = False
obj.solution_for = ''
del obj.solution_for
```

But I guess i have to give in.. What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Correct way is to set this field to `None`:

```
obj.solution_for = None
obj.save()
```